# Azure cloud service run PowerShell script post deployment

Tags: powershell, azure, asp.net-web-api, iis-7, azure-cloud-services

I have an Azure cloud service and wants website appPool to recycle at a scheduled time instead of periodic time. 
So I have created a PowerShell script to do the changes and executes the PS script through command using task.
But it won't work because Azure deployment task runs before deployment not after.
So, I added the sleep to my task and started it as a background task.

```
<Task commandLine="..\StartUpScripts\StartPool.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background">
</Task>
```

Below is StartPool.cmd

```
Powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -File ..\..\approot\StartUpScripts\pool.ps1 
EXIT /B 0
```

Below is the pool.ps1

```
# Set the cloud service apppool recycle time to schedule time

# ** Import WebAdministration Module **
Import-Module WebAdministration

# List all sites, applications and appPools
while(!($myWeb = Get-Website -name "*mySiteName*")){
    Write-Host "Website not installed. Waiting 10 seconds..."
    Start-Sleep 10
}
$poolName = $myWeb.applicationPool

$resetTime = "09:00"

$poolPath="IIS:\AppPools\" + $poolName      
Set-ItemProperty -Path $poolPath -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule -Value @{value=$resetTime}
Set-ItemProperty -Path $poolPath -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.time -Value 00:00:00

exit 0
```

Folder Structure is like

```
Roles
--MyWebSite
----StartUpScripts
------StartPool.cmd
------pool.ps1
```

But it's not working. If I execute the script by logging on the server it works.
Please help, thanks in Advance.

Comment: you should add logging and see whats going wrong

Comment: tried adding event logging when I started task as background nothing happens and when as simple task process stuck, which is expected because site deploys only after all task completes.